# Why does set subtraction and .difference() run at different speeds

Tags: python, set, cpython, pypy, timeit

To find the difference between two sets there is the `-` operator and `.difference()`. I'm using this code to time each of those:

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit('''
a.difference({b})
                    ''', setup='''
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
b = 3
                    '''))
# => 0.2423834060318768

print(timeit.timeit('''
a - {b}
                    ''', setup='''
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
b = 3
                    '''))
# => 0.2027170000365004
```

When I run this in CPython I get this:

```
0.24530324200168252
0.205820870003663
```

This made sense to me because `.difference()` can take any iterable, not just sets. However, when I run it in PyPy I get this:

```
0.14613953093066812
0.23659668595064431
```

The times are completely flipped, so surely it can't be because `.difference()` can take any interable. What is the difference between the implementations of `.difference()` and `-`? Is there any difference between CPython and PyPy's implementations?

Comment: Wonder if you can try some *bigger* sets to further confirm the timing difference?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c   <--- CPython implementation.

Comment: I wonder if a single bound method `a.difference` is getting shared between tests, whereas `a - {b}` requires a new bound method for `a.__sub__` to be generated for each test. That could certainly make the method call seem faster in PyPy, since the JIT can do less work over a large number of iterations.

Comment: I dunno about PyPy, but neither version actually generates a bound method object in CPython. `-` goes right to the type object's `nb_subtract` function pointer, while with `difference`, the interpreter detects that this is an ordinary method type with known binding semantics and optimizes out the actual method binding operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PyPy, there is an optimization that is invoked by `difference()` but not by `__sub__()`: when you use `a.difference(b)` and `b` is a smaller set than `a`, then it copies `a` completely and removes the items from `b`.  If it's not the case, it starts from an empty set and adds the items of `a` that are not in `b`.  For some reason `__sub__()` doesn't go through the path that selects between these two implementations, and always picks the second logic.

Please report it on https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues and it will likely be fixed.